# C++ split class Tree with a very related data into two classes

Tags: c++, architecture, tree

I have a class `Tree`:

```cpp
class Tree {
    string aboutTree;
    vector<int> veryImportantInfo;
    Tree* leftChild;
    Tree* rightChild;
    ...
    void veryImportantMethod() {
        // change and use aboutTree
        // change and use veryImportantInfo
    }
};
```

`aboutTree` and `veryImportantInfo` are not constant, but same for all nodes of tree and I don't want to replicate it in all nodes. I want something like this:

```cpp
class Tree {
    //string aboutTree;
    //vector<int> veryImportantInfo;
    Tree* leftChild;
    Tree* rightChild;
    ...
    void veryImportantMethod() {
        // change and use aboutTree
        // change and use veryImportantInfo
    }
};

class TreeWrapper {
    string aboutTree;
    vector<int> veryImportantInfo;
    Tree root;
    ...

};
```

But isn't work because I have no access to non-static fields of `TreeWrapper`.

Comment: Can you please show your code in your `main` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible crude solutions I came up wit h was to have all branches link back to the wrapper and access the data directly:

*Note I replaced*`TreeWrapper` *with* `Tree` *and* `Tree` *with* `branch`, *because it makes more sense to me.*

```
class tree
{
public:
    struct branch
    {
        branch* leftChild;
        branch* rightChild;
        tree* parent;
        void veryImportantMethod() {
            // change and use parent->aboutTree
            // change and use parent->veryImportantInfo
        }
    };
    tree() { root.parent = this; }
    tree root;
    string aboutTree;
    vector<int> veryImportantInfo;
};
```

Whenever you create a new `branch` you will need to have `leftChild->parent = parent;`.  And you would also want to define member functions of `branch` to do that for you as you would in a doubly linked list.

Another solution would be to use a actual doubly linked list format. So `tree* parent` would be `branch* parent`.  Accessing the important info from a branch would not be as fast as above but it would be mean it would be more navigable. You could travel up around the tree more easily.  (Actually having both `tree* root` and `branch* parent` might not be a bad idea. But the finer details are up to you.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the first of your solutions.